# Why does my keyboard suddenly stop working?

Tags: 14.04, wireless, keyboard

I have been using dual-boot on a Lenovo Flex for about 3 weeks now with Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04.

Ubuntu started getting funny with unreliable connection (Wifi was connecting but not transfering data.) the same happened with cable

3 days ago it suddenly started to work fine for 1 hour then came funny again and accompanied by my keyboard not responding.

It works when I type my login but not once I am logged in. It works when I am under a guest session and it works with Windows.

There is no difference whether I use the on board keyboard or a USB keyboard. So it's not a hardware / driver issue.

Can anyone explain?

**Update**:
Thanks for asking. Yes, I think the issue was raised following some update (although not immediately after) and yes, I have managed to run updates both via the updater and via the apt-get update command. Nothing changed even after reboot.

Regards

Thanks for asking and your input. Yes, I think the issue was raised following some update (although not immediately after) and yes, I have managed to run updates both via the updater and via the apt-get update command. Nothing changed even after reboot.

Replying to the question "Can you get to TTY with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>?"
Nope1 The only key that works is the airplane mode one which is on <kbd>F7</kbd>. I can get to the terminal if I have prepared what I need to type beforehand with windows or another computer / phone then saving a Gedit doc...

A question:
Would a restore be possible and if yes would it help? My data is on a separate partition which I can easily back-up via Windows. Tks

Gnome-Do is not running and impossible to copy / print-screen the list of applications to display here.

No possibility to use the terminal as Enter key does not work either...

Comment: Have you installed updates from the Software Installer? I had this issue and since updating, everything has been working fine. So I want to ask about this first before recommending other things.

Comment: Have you installed GNOME-Do or something similar?

Comment: Does the mouse still work then?  Have you tried another keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Try this
So, to fix this, go to:

System Settings → Universal Access → Typing (tab): switch off "Slow keys"

Also switch off "Enable by Keyboard" if you want to stop it happening again.

It don't know why the login screen ignores this setting, tho.

Update

I just did this again (d'oh!) which brought me back to this answer and gave me the initiative to find out what triggered it.

Apparently, if you have Enable by keyboard on and then you hold down the Shift key for eight seconds, it will enable/disable slowkeys.

This was a new setup, and I had enabled Enable by keyboard because I wanted a way to flip between touchscreen and keyboard mode easily. Might not be worth the effort, tho!

Thanks to tudor, I guess.
[All keyboards stopped working after login screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/648886/all-keyboards-stopped-working-after-login-screen?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if it's worth mentioning, but i had a similar problem with Ubuntu 20.04 where the keyboard inputs stopped registering (although the keyboard seemed to be working fine, turning the LEDs on/off)

Although not a proper fix, i managed to get it working again by using the mouse to lock the screen (upper right). Then the keyboard worked when i tried to input my password.

Answer (score -1):

An application seems to be messing with the keyboard. Trying to stop such an application like that (like "GNOME Do" or similar) would be my first guess.

I'm assuming this, since they keyboard works before logging in and since it works in a guest session. Also I don't think it's driver related (or graphics related), for the same reasons. So an application seems to load for this one user and mess things up.

Can you get to TTY with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>?

Comment: I've posted a the question as a comment to the OP.

Comment: Super vague answer. Try *how?*